# Using I2S microphone with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, audio, i2s

I have a microphone with I2S output and I am trying to record audio with it, using the Raspberry Pi (2 model B). I'm having trouble getting the microphone to work.
Does anyone have working code for it? I didn't find such information on the internet.

Comment: specify the brand and model of your microphone.

Comment: I found a nice guide by adafruit, chck it out!
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test